# Mismatched linetypes in plot and legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, facet-wrap

I plot this [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1KJEfQoow_3S2hNak5ob3BETTQ) using the following code

```
df = read.csv(file = "data.csv");
p = ggplot(data = df) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=yp,linetype="dashed")) + 
geom_line(aes(x=x,y=yi,linetype="solid")) + facet_wrap(~s) + labs(y="y");
```

I am getting the following [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OedX.png).

The code says to draw dashed line using `yp` variable and to draw solid line using `yi` variable. But what we see in the plot is the other way round (if you take a look at the data). Linetypes in the legend are also mismatched. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: add `linetype` outside `aes` as `geom_line(aes(...), linetype="")`

Comment: But then the legend disappears.

Comment: just updated solution for that

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you just need to modify placement of `linetype` inside `geom_line` function.

Further to add legend and colors to distinguish yp and yi, use :

```
p = ggplot(data = df) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=yp,colour="darkblue"), linetype="dotted", show.legend = TRUE) + 
+     geom_line(aes(x=x,y=yi,colour="red"), linetype="solid", show.legend = TRUE) + facet_wrap(~s) + labs(y="y") +scale_color_discrete(name = "Y series", labels = c("yp", "yi"))
```

**Result**
[image: snap1]

Comment: Almost what I want. I simply want to distinguish two lines in each subplot somehow (say, by linetype) and to mention this distinction in the legend. In your example, the lines are distinguished by two properties: linetype and colour which is superfluous. I guess the crude way would be to use scale_linetype_manual?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution for you:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

data <- structure(list(x = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), yp = c(0.469718933105469, 
                                                                     0.00809860229492188, 0.469718933105469, 0.041229248046875, 0.469718933105469, 
                                                                     0.12957763671875, 0.469718933105469, 0.284187316894531), yi = c(0.00809860229492188, 
                                                                                                                                     0.0212535858154297, 0.041229248046875, 0.1033935546875, 0.12957763671875, 
                                                                                                                                     0.28466796875, 0.284187316894531, 0.469718933105469), s = c("q1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "q1", "q2", "q2", "q3", "q3", "q4", "q4")), .Names = c("x", "yp", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "yi", "s"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "data.frame"))
data <-  melt(data,id=c("x","s"))

ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=value,linetype=variable)) + geom_line() + scale_linetype_discrete(labels=c("solid","dashed")) + facet_wrap(~s)
```

at first i have melted the data with help of `reshape2` package, and further used it in `ggplot()`. I have used as well `scale_linetype_discrete()` which has an argument `labels =` to change the legend text to solid and dashed, instead of yp and yi.

[image]

Comment: what is "X1"? (Error: id variables not found in data: X1)

Comment: ah sorry, wait a sec, this happened during downlaoding of data --> X1 appeared as row names

Comment: check now the code please, i have removed "X1" from melt

Comment: The plot is perfect, but I get a completly different one using your code

Comment: Thats weird, please run the full code i have posted now, it reads at first your data and then performs melt and plotting